# Mostrar um link da base de Dados em React.js

Tags: react, firebase

Bom dia caros colaboradores, o meu  problema é o seguinte: Ao criar um campo na firebase que contêm um link e ao pedir no código que o chame , o React entende que o campo pretendido é um text invés de ser uma hiperligação . Alguém me consegue ajudar?
Aqui está o código:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const IndividualProduct = ({individualProduct, addToCart}) => {

    const handleAddToCart=()=>{
        addToCart(individualProduct);
    }   
    return (
        <div className='product'>
            <div className='product-img'>
                <img src={individualProduct.url} alt="product-img"/>
            </div>
            <div className='product-text title'>{individualProduct.title}</div>
            <div className='product-text description'>{individualProduct.description}</div>
            <div className='product-text price'>{individualProduct.price}€</div>
           <div className='product-text stripe'>{individualProduct.stripe}</div>
            <div className='btn btn-danger btn-md cart-btn' onClick={handleAddToCart}>Adicione ao carrinho</div>            
        </div> 
    )
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARXfT.png
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom dia,
Depois de ler o seu codigo, creio que a solução será esta:

```
<div><a href={individualProduct.stripe}>Pagamento</a></div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado